# SharePoint PowerShell Client how to manage Workflow Events

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, powershell

I'm working on SharePoint Online site, and i need to desactivate a workflow when updating some values with PowerShell.

Do you know if it's possible to modify EventTypes of an existing workflow dynamically with PowerShell?

I tried with this sample of code but no changes

```
# Connect
Connect-SPOnline -Url $webURL -Credentials $cred
$web = Get-SPOWeb

$list = Get-SPOList -Identity /Lists/List001

# Get subscription
$WFSub = Get-SPOWorkflowSubscription -Name "Workflow001"

# Set events
$WFSub.EventTypes.Remove("ItemAdded") | Out-Null

$web.Context.Load($WFSub)
$web.Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

I tried to apply changes with this sample of code, not working too :(

```
# Publish changes
$servicesManager = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($list.Context, $list.ParentWeb)
$subscriptionService = $servicesManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()
$subscriptionResult = $subscriptionService.PublishSubscriptionForList($WFSub, $list.Id);
```

subscriptionResult returns:

```
Value                               
-----                               
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

I don't understand what is happen but no changes got effect on the workflow. I don't have any idea how to resolve this issue.

This script must modify those options:
[image: Workflow start options]

Any help will be appreciated. Hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

try PowerShell pnp, it should be helpful.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/RemoveSPOEventReceiver.md

Comment: Can you please be more specific regarding how this relates to the question above, and how it should be implemented?

Comment: u don't even read did u?

Comment: Did I not? You post a link to documentation for how to remove an event receiver with PnP PowerShell. The question is regarding to updating an existing workflow definition. To me, there is a gap

Comment: yes, the answer is not 100%, then I get a minus, hopeless place

Comment: You get voted down when you post answers not at all related to a question. This community works like this: Someone asks a question, users answer the question with qualitative and relevant responses. Yours are neither right now

Comment: You can read the guidelines in the helpcenter here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer if you are interested